# Си, Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения

Tags: c

Нужно найти минимальное положительное число и вывести среднее арифметическое после последнего максимального четного элемента. Выдает ошибку при отладке. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код main:

```
int main() {
 int n, i, min, av;
 int *a;
 printf("input n: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);

 a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("a[%d] = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
 }
 printf("========================================\n");
 min = MIN(n, a);
 printf("MIN = %d", min);
 av = Average(n, a);
 if (av = 1) {
    printf("No average");
 }
 else {
    printf("Average = %d", av);
 }
 printf("========================================\n");

 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Код функции MIN:

```
int MIN(int *a, int n) {
int i = 0;
int min = 0;
do {
    if (a[i] > 0) {
        min = a[i];
        i++;
    }
} while (i <= n);

if (min == 0) {
    return -1;
}
else {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] > 0) {
            if (a[i] < min) {
                min = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
}
```

На всякий случай код функции Average:

```
int Average(int *a, int n) {
int lmax = 1;
int num = 0;
int k = 0;
int sum = 0;
int av = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
        lmax = a[i];
    }
}

if (lmax == 1) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((a[i] > lmax) && (a[i] % 2 == 0)) {
            lmax = a[i];
            num = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = num + 1; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + a[i];
        k++;
    }

    av = sum / k;

    return av;
}
}
```

При работе в консоли после ввода массива вылетает программа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

ошибка была в том, что аргументы при вызове функция не так указаны (перепутаны)

Answer (score 3):

Ну так вы выделяете `n` элементов:

```
a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

а читаете `n+1`-й:

```
} while (i <= n);
```

Ну нет в массиве `a[n]` элемента `a[n]` - последний `a[n-1]`...

Comment: то есть, нужно вместо while (i <= n) написать while (i <= (n-1))? если вы имели в виду это, то даже после исправления появляется та же ошибка

Comment: @Александр: В цикле чтения у вас условие записано как `i < n`. Откуда у вас вдруг возникает странная идея сформулировать то же условие как `i <= (n-1)`? Это вообще ваш код?

Comment: @Ant: да, мой, просто я запутался и не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Просто уберите знак равно `while (i < n);` - вам же все описали подробно